# Запись и подсчёт повторяющихся строк C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Я получаю из запроса список объектов. У них есть строковое поле. Мне нужно пройти по этим объектам, выбрать у каждого объекта строковое поле, а затем записать эти поля в какую-то структуру данных, при этом нужно как-то учесть повторяющиеся строки и вывести количество повторений, если они есть.

```
var get = api.Wall.Get(new WallGetParams { OwnerId = x, Count = 100, Extended = true });
string title;                                                                     
foreach (var z in get.Groups)
{
    title = z.ScreenName;
    // ?
    // ?
    // ?
}
```

Comment: точку с запятой потеряли в строке **string title**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя LINQ:

```
var query = from z in get.Groups
            group z by z.ScreenName into res
            select new {Name = res.Key, Repeats = res.Count()};
foreach (var val in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Значение: {val.Name} Повторений: {val.Repeats}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, использовать словарь. Должно получиться что-то типо такого:

```
Dictionary<string, int> titles = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var z in get.Groups)
{
    if (!titles.ContainsKey(z.ScreeeName)) titles.Add(z.ScreenName,1);
    else titles[z.ScreenName]++;
}
```